# How to change the width and height of a tooltip

Tags: jquery, asp.net, popup, tooltip

I have a tree view.In child node, Onmouseover, I have to display some contents on a tool tip or popup. The content is large. As of now, i have used a popup, which is not looking good.  Tooltip seems to be neat, but all my contents are not getting displayed.. Is there any way to sortout this one..

Code

```
var oPopup = window.createPopup();

function richToolTip(Target) {
 var lefter = event.offsetY + 0;
 var topper = event.offsetX + 15;
 oPopup.document.body.innerHTML = '<div style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;' + ' border: 2px solid black; ' + 'font: normal 10pt tahoma; filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(GradientType=0,' + ' StartColorStr=gold, EndColorStr=#FFFFFF); padding: 10px;">' + '<b>Node Name</b><hr style="border: 1px solid black;"> <b>Node Name:' + Target.innerText + '</b><br/><imgsrc="peoplewithmedicare.tmf.org/Portals/17/Icons/icon_excel.jpg"; alt="Image"></img> <br/>' + '<hr style="border: 1px solid black;"></div>';
 oPopup.show(topper, lefter, 170, 120, RFPPlaceHolder_TVContent);
}

function AddAttributes() {
 var TreeNodes = RFPPlaceHolder_TVContent.getElementsByTagName('TABLE');
 for (var i = 0; i < TreeNodes.length; i++) {
    TreeNodes[i].onmouseover = function setToolTip() {
        richToolTip(this);
    };
    TreeNodes[i].onmouseout = function removeToolTip() {
        oPopup.hide();
    };
 }
}​
```

Comment: Since ther is no much space in comment box, i ll split the code and post it twice.

Comment: var oPopup = window.createPopup(); function richToolTip(Target) {
var lefter = event.offsetY + 0; var topper = event.offsetX + 15; oPopup.document.body.innerHTML = '<div style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;' + ' border: 2px solid black; ' + 'font: normal 10pt tahoma; filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(GradientType=0,' + ' StartColorStr=gold, EndColorStr=#FFFFFF); padding: 10px;">' + '<b>Node Name</b><hr style="border: 1px solid black;"> <b>Node Name:' + Target.innerText +

Comment: '</b><br/><imgsrc="http://peoplewithmedicare.tmf.org/Portals/17/Icons/icon_excel.jpg" alt="Image"></img> <br/>' + '<hr style="border: 1px solid black;"></div>';  oPopup.show(topper, lefter, 170, 120, RFPPlaceHolder_TVContent);} function AddAttributes() {  var TreeNodes = RFPPlaceHolder_TVContent.getElementsByTagName('TABLE'); for (var i = 0; i < TreeNodes.length; i++) {    TreeNodes[i].onmouseover = function setToolTip() { richToolTip(this); };  TreeNodes[i].onmouseout = function removeToolTip() { oPopup.hide(); };  }  }

Comment: Anooz insted of writing on comment ,why donot you answer the question?

Comment: I tried to answer the question,. Since I am a new user to stack overflow. I am unable to answer for my own question. Only after ten posts i will be able to answer it seems.. :(